# Is Levenshtein distance transitive?

Tags: algorithms

If I define some arbitrary similarity metric for Levenshtein distance

$$ \mathrm{Sim}(A,B) = \text{true} \mathrel{{>}\mkern-13mu{<}} \mathrm{Lev}(A,B)\le 3 $$

e.g. If $L(A,B) \le 3$ is "similar", what can be said about the transitivity of this "similarity" operation?

If $S(A,B)$ holds, and $S(B,C)$ holds, does it imply $S(A,C)$?

I can give proof that it does not:

- L("cato", "catalog") = 3
- L("tlog", "catalog") = 3
- L("cato", "tlog")    = 4

But still, it seems that something subtler can be said about this operation. It seems likely that if I describe $L(A,B)\le 3$ as "1 degree of separation," and $L(A,B)\le 6$ as "2 degrees of separation," then rather than transitivity, if $L(A,B)$ is 1 degree of separation and $L(B,C)$ is 1 degree of separation, then $L(A,C)$ is at most 2 degrees of separation.

In other words, if:

- All the words w/in 1 degree of separation of A are a set called A'
- And all the words w/in 2 degrees of separation of A are a set called A''

Then if I were to generate a similar set for any member of A' (e.g. all of the words within 1 degree of separation from the member of A'), then all words within 1 degree of separation of any member of A' is also a member of A''.

This strikes me as likely to be true, but I'm having difficulty proving it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does Levenshtein distance satisfy the triangle inequality?

Comment: @Brian: Yes, all [edit distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) with symmetric non-negative costs are metrics. Brett: I think the concept you're looking for is that of a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).

Comment: Interesting @BrianTung! I'll look into it :)

Comment: @Rahul: It was intended as a hint, but the more general rule is interesting, thanks!

Comment: @BrianTung neither hint actually gave me much insight into the matter without further digging and then they both seemed immediately apparent :)

Comment: Alas, such is the way of hints. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! After taking your advice, I've discovered you both handed me the answer :)

Since Levenshtein distance is a metric, and the triangle inequality holds, then:

$$ L(A,C) <= L(A,B) + L(B,C) $$

So it doesn't matter what threshold we define the Sim(a, b) function to have, at most Sim(A,C) will be `2*L(A,B)`.

Therefore all matches for any member of `A'` will contain all of its matches in `A''`.